# Datetimepicker conditional statement visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

Seems as I research and understand the code. It didn‘t follow the way when if its detected minor. Where from 2014 to above there's no error but 2014 and below  comes up an error.

I wanted to know on how to test based on today's date in correct way so that when I put year 1993 then its allowed.

Assuming I will use the datetimepicker from toolbox.

```
If (DateTime.Now.Subtract(Birthdate.Value.AddYears(18)). TotalDays >= 0)
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct way of code.

Comment: we cant tell you whats wrong with your code if you dont share it

Comment: If (DateTime.Now.Subtract(Birthdate.Value.AddYears(18)). TotalDays >= 0) this is the if statement assume I used the Birthdate as date time picker however it doesn‘t recognize 2014 below.

Comment: @jamescv31 please edit your original question and paste the code there.

Answer (score 0):

This will tell you if someone is over 18

```
' underage person (roughly 16 years old)
Dim birthday1 As New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year - 16, 2, 15)
' person's 18th birthday is today
Dim birthday2 = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year - 18, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day)
' roughly 20 year old person
Dim birthday3 As New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year - 20, 10, 6)
' method 1 using all DateTime functions
Debug.Print(birthday1.AddYears(18).CompareTo(DateTime.Now)) ' 1
Debug.Print(birthday2.AddYears(18).CompareTo(DateTime.Now)) ' -1
Debug.Print(birthday3.AddYears(18).CompareTo(DateTime.Now)) ' -1
' method 2
Debug.Print(DateTime.Now.Subtract(birthday1.AddYears(18)).Days >= 0) ' false
Debug.Print(DateTime.Now.Subtract(birthday2.AddYears(18)).Days >= 0) ' true
Debug.Print(DateTime.Now.Subtract(birthday3.AddYears(18)).Days >= 0) ' true
```

Personally, I would put it inside an extension method on `DateTime`

```
Module ExtensionMethods

    <Extension()>
    Public Function IsOlderThan(dt As DateTime, age As Integer) As Boolean
        Return dt.AddYears(age).CompareTo(DateTime.Now) = -1
    End Function

End Module
```

Usage:

```
Dim isOfAge = birthday.IsOlderThan(18) ' true or false
```

Comment: Where is the DateTimePicker that I will use when added in the toolbox when its a declared object only?

Comment: I'm bit confused on where I will put BirthDate (as my DateTimePicker on that codes)

Comment: The DateTimePicker.Value property returns the DateTime. Use that

Comment: In what way I will put the code based on your post? the DatetimePicker (BirthDate as added in my program)  Sincr the way I encode is likely invalid for me.

Comment: There's more than enough information here to solve your problem.